# How to get byte[] data of a bitmap in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, image-processing, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to read an image into a byte array.

using my xaml, I have a binding for my image:

```
    <Image x:Name="myImageView"
           Source="triangles.bmp"
           Aspect="AspectFit" 
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

I would like to have the data from myImageView into a byte array.
What code can accomplish this **on xamarin forms**?

I have found solutions for the other way around (which i haven't tested yet), but I need this way (bound image->byte[], not byte[]->Image).

My usage will be, for example, to apply a bluring convolution filter, or to find the max pixel value.

Thanks.

Comment: You can just read it from disk into a byte[].  But the Image control doesn't provide any mechanism to access it's internal image data.

Comment: @Jason allright, then I'll read it from disk. How can this be done? I've been looking for literaly hours and found nothing. Plase give a code snippet

Comment: are you using a PCL or a shared project?  And where is your image stored?  Is it part of the app bundle, or a camera image, etc?

Comment: @Jason I am using PCL

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using PCL, you can achieve this by using the interface I created below and registering it with Xamarin DependencyService.

I provided methods to get bytes from an **URIImageSource** & **FileImageSource**

**In Your PCL Project**

```
private void ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ(){
    var link = new Uri("https://xamarin.com/content/images/pages/forms/example-app.png");
    var goNative = DependencyService.Get<IStackoverflow>();
    var bytes = goNative.GetImageBytes(link);   // Your Bytes As Requested
}

public interface IStackoverflow  // Create an interface to access platform specific
{
    byte[] GetImageBytes(string filepath);
    byte[] GetImageBytes(Uri uri);
}
```

**In your native project**  make sure you inherit from the above interface.

> If you're not accessing it from your PCL project then,

```
imagePath = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.triangles.bmp);
```

```
public byte[] GetImageBytes(string imagePath)
{
    var fileStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    var buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
    fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
    fileStream.Close();
    return buffer;
}

public byte[] GetImageBytes(Uri uri)
{
    var myWebClient = new WebClient();
    return  myWebClient.DownloadData(uri);
}
```

If you're unfamiliar with Xamarin DependencyService, here is their documentation
[Xamarin DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/)

Comment: Thanks! this is very close to working, but I am getting an exception from the android part, when I try to access the image. Should I state the path differently in android or in Xamaril forms portable? In Xamarin forms, "triangles.bmp" works. In android, it doesn't find the file.

Comment: Im assuming this image is part of your project since it works for you in forms if your trying to access it only from your native android project the full filepath will need to be use as the filename for example if the image is in your drawable folder the file name should be Resource.Drawable.triangles.bmp

Comment: with dots? not slashes? why is that? Also, where can I find the official doc about this?

Comment: Dots because resource.drawable is android class. Doc.. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Comment: imagePath = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.triangles.bmp);

Comment: `var imagePath = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.triangles.bmp);` gives errors: 1. the name Resource does not exist in the current context.  2. an object reference is required for the non static field, method, or property VisualElement.Resources. If i use the quick fix and add `using Android.Resource`, then i get 1. Resource.Drawable does not contain a definition for triangles.bmp 2. same as before. Aay idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128481/discussion-between-themofade-and-gulzar).

Comment: If you don't have time to post the full answer (in chat) I would be happy if you just direct me what to do or where to look for a solution, as this kind of urgent for me. Thanks!